# Перенос атрибутов фолдеров при их копировании в Windows Explorer

Tags: windows

При копировании папок с помощью Windows Explorer нужно копировать и атрибуты этих папок (в частности Read Only). На некоторых машинах они копируются, на некоторых нет. Есть ли какая-то настройка, отвечающая за это поведение? Использование других программ и утилит не подходит, интересует именно настройка Windows Explorer.

Comment: Ты про `robocopy`?

Comment: Нет. Я про настройки Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

В Windows 10 был баг, из-за которого атрибуты не копировались: [Folder attributes/customization lost on copy or move in Windows 10 1607 (Anniversary Update)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab1a753-9a63-4273-8ba4-0d0748cc9ac0/folder-attributescustomization-lost-on-copy-or-move-in-windows-10-1607-anniversary-update?forum=win10itprogeneral)

Вероятно, на этих "некоторых машинах" как раз и стоит такая бажная версия Windows.